# Extra pixels below my html table

Tags: html, css, joomla, html-table

I am creating a website in joomla with the helix3 framework and there is some issue what I am unable to solve.

I have some extra pixels below my html table on the top of the page "::: ÉLŐ KÖZVETÍTÉS :::"
on the site: http://ocsaibaptista.hu

For some reason the "sp-column" class gives 7 extra pixels to the bottom of the content.
The height should be 24px but for some reason it is 31px.

Could anyone please explain why it is having the extra pixels?

Comment: `body { line-height: 24px } ` << This is what is causing the additional spacing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `height: 25px;` on this element : `.sp-column.live_header`